# convert named vector to list but keep vector names

Tags: r, list, vector, names

I have a named vector that I want to convert to a list, as such:

```
a = 1:10
names(a) = letters[1:10]
as.list(a)
$a
[1] 1
$b
[1] 2
$c
[1] 3
```

Here, the names of each vector is now the name of the list, but I need the vectors within the list to keep their names, like this:

```
as.list(a)
$a
a
1
$b
b
2
$c
c
3
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: My question is very different. The solutions posted below (which are simple and worked) were not mentioned at all in that question.

Comment: Did you check the first  and accepted solution in that question? You can easily adapt it to your requirement for this question.

Comment: I reopened this question.  I don't believe it's a duplicate of the linked question, and 4 out of the 5 duplicate voters were not R users.  You can derive answers from other answers all over this site, but that does not mean the questions are duplicates of each other.  If you can get 5 R users to agree to that duplicate then I might change my mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `split()`.

```
split(a, names(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

One option after going ahead with `as.list` is to the set the names of the elements with the corresponding `names` of original `vector` with `Map`

```
Map(setNames, as.list(a), names(a))
#$a
#a 
#1 

#$b
#b 
#2 

#$c
#c 
#3 

#$d
#d 
#4 

#$e
#e 
#5 

#$f
#f 
#6 

#$g
#g 
#7 

#$h
#h 
#8 

#$i
#i 
#9 

#$j
# j 
#10
```